# Related entities EF Count

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, count, foreign-keys

Need help. I want count players from clubs and show how much players are playing in club. This is my View [image]

But i want that my code show player count in club, like this 
[image]

Here is my database structure :
[image]

My starting code

```
 public int GetCountOfPlayersInClub(int clubId)
    {
        using (var db = new BasketDbContext())
        {
            return db.Player.Count(p => p.BasketBallClubId == clubId);
        }
    }
```

But what I do now, what I need write in my ActionResult Index()?

Comment: Use a view model containing the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display value in view, you need to pass it over model or viewbag.
In view you can call the passed variable via razor syntax (like @Viebag.CountAll).

Note that count is not very optimized in ef core and I would recommend to ran raw query for it.in testing I did , raw query is 100 times faster.